# Display query without character input

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-events

I'm having problems with a "google like" search engine .
When the page loads, it expects a character in the input box to display inside a div the results.

What can I do to display all the database contents without typing any character in the input box?
Below are the three files:

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
Caută analizele în baza noastră de date.<br>Taxa de urgență este de 35 Ron
<p align ="right">
<input type="text" id="go" class="field" name="go" onclick="this.value='';" onfocus="this.select()" onblur="this.value=!this.value?'Caută analiza dorită':this.value;" value="Caută analiza dorită"/>
<input type="submit" name="search" id="submit" value="Cauta" /><br/>
<div id="search_query"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/instant.js"></script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Search.php

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");

mysql_select_db("db");
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $conn);
         

if(isset($_POST['search_query'])){
$search_query = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['search_query']));


$search_query_x = explode(",",$search_query);   

foreach($search_query_x as $search_each){
@$x++;
if($x==1)
@$construct.="Den LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct.="AND Den LIKE '%s$search_each%'";
}
$construct ="SELECT * FROM biochimie1 WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($construct) or die(mysql_error());
$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
// Define $color=1
$color="1";
if ($foundnum==0){
echo "Ne pare rau dar nu există rezultate pentru <strong><font color='red'>$search_query</font></strong></br></br> Vă rugăm să verificați dacă ați scris corect";
}
else{
echo'<p align="center">';
echo "$foundnum \n";
echo ' rezultate găsite în urma căutării!</p>';
        echo "<table id='table1' border='0'width='500'>         
<tr>
<th width='150' align='center' valign='middle'>Denumire Analize</th>
<th width='50' align='center' valign='middle'>Preț</th>
<th width='100' align='center' valign='middle'>Zile de recoltare</th>
<th width='100' align='center' valign='middle'>Termen de eliberare a rezultatelor</th>
<th width='100' align='center' valign='middle'>Se poate lucra în regim de urgență</th>
</tr></table>";
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
    $NrCrt = $runrows ['NrCrt'];
    $denanalize = $runrows ['Den'];
    $pret = $runrows ['Pret'];
    $rec = $runrows ['Rec'];
    $rez = $runrows ['Rez'];
    $obs = $runrows ['Obs'];
  echo "<table border='0'>";
  // If $color==1 table row color = #FFC600
if($color==1){
echo "
  <tr bgcolor='#efefef'>
    <td width='150' align='center' valign='middle'>$denanalize</td>
    <td width='50' align='center' valign='middle'>$pret</td>
    <td width='100' align='center' valign='middle'>$rec</td>
    <td width='100' align='center' valign='middle'>$rez</td>
    <td width='100' align='center' valign='middle'>$obs</td>
  </tr>
</table>";
// Set $color==2, for switching to other color
$color="2";
}
// When $color not equal 1, use this table row color
else {
echo "<tr bgcolor='#eaeaea'>
    <td width='150' align='center' valign='middle'>$denanalize</td>
    <td width='50' align='center' valign='middle'>$pret</td>
    <td width='100' align='center' valign='middle'>$rec</td>
    <td width='100' align='center' valign='middle'>$rez</td>
    <td width='100' align='center' valign='middle'>$obs</td>
  </tr>";
  // Set $color back to 1
$color="1";
}echo "
</table>";
}
}
}
else{
    echo 'An ERROR has occured';
}
?>
```

and instant.js file

```
$('#go').keyup(function(){
                        var search_query=$(this).val();
                        $.post('search.php', {search_query: search_query},function(searchq){
                        $('#search_query').html(searchq);
                    });
});
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: logic flaw: you escape your entire query string, then chop it up into pieces. While this particular bit of code isn't a problem, you should **NEVER** manipulate an escaped string. You risk undoing all of the escaping and STILL leaving yourself open to sql injection.

Comment: what do you mean Marc B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work on load:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                        var search_query=$(this).val();
                        $.post('search.php', {search_query: search_query},function(searchq){
                        $('#search_query').html(searchq);
                    });
```

Comment: and where shall i put this code? inside .js file? already did that and didn't work...

Comment: there are no errors... the codes work well... but i want to have the whole contents of the database displayed and then only if i want to search something, the script should do his thing...

Comment: solved with your ideea... just that i replaced:
    `$(document).ready(function(){`
with 
    `$('#go').ready(function(){`